# How to output {name} in xml of scala, not convert it?

Tags: xml, scala

```
val name = "mike"
val xml = <name>{name}</name>
```

xml will be `<name>mike</name>`

But what if I want the xml be `<name>{name}</name>`, not convert the `{name}`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can escape the curly braces by doubling them

```
val xml = <name>{{name}}</name>
```

will give you

```
<name>{name}</name>
```

Answer (score 6):

To complement other answers, you can also provide a `Text` node inside your XML literal:

```
import scala.xml.Text

<xml> {
  Text("{foo}")
} </xml>
```

will produce,

```
<xml> {foo} </xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use the xml entities for `{ }` and not `{ }` themselves.

For example:

```
val name = "mike"
val xml = <name>&#123;name&#125;</name>
```